# how MergeContent keep order when merging

Tags: apache-nifi

[image]

at line 270, use `HashMap` to group flowfiles, then iterate entrySet() to add flowfile to readyBins.

[image]

If `Correlation Attribute Name` is not set and `Merge Strategy` is set to `Bin-Packing Algorithm`,  how can MergeContent keep flowfiles order in which they are pulled from the queue?

Answer (score 0):

I know why can keep order if Correlation Attribute Name not specified, as only one key `null` in hashmap.  I wonder should `LinkedHashMap` better?